# Изменить иконку приложения на рабочем столе

Tags: изображения, icon, blazor

при установки веб приложения блазор с браузера, на рабочий стол сохраняется приложение, с иконкой по умолчанию `blazor`

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon-192.png" />
```

чтоб их изменить, [тут](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/create-pwa-from-blazor-app) предлагают простое решение, просто изменить их в папке `wwwroot`,

[тут](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) можно создать различные размеры для иконок,

[тут](https://www.pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter) я попыталась понять `px` и `dp` разницу,

но только вот у меня на рабочем столе все еще нет лого на приложении и блазорское удалилось, кто подскажет как можно правильно подобрать размер, и внедрить свою иконку и какая для чего нужна имено тут `512 и 192`

мой png/icon, которым я пытаюсь заменить те, что по умолчанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто уже менял эти иконки успешно, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я подобрала верный размер, заменила их в папке `wwwroot` и теперь если нажать, чтоб скачать например веб приложение с навигатора, то иконка применяется.
Я использовала [сайт](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_example) чтоб подобрать размер 512 и 192
Когда я задавала этот вопрос я думала, что `css` сам подгонит размеры, но оказывается, нужно необходимый размер иконки сохранить.
[по варианту,](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/create-pwa-from-blazor-app)  просто заменила имеющиеся на свои

- правда пока еще не поняла зачем там два размера какой для чего